# consuming REST server methods from BizTalk Server using WCF-WebHttp adapter

Tags: rest, biztalk, url-mapping, biztalk-orchestrations, webhttp

I'm using VS 2019 and BTS 2020 developer edition. I need to implement a scenario in which BizTalk sits between the client and the REST server (implemented in APS.NET Core) and the client send request to BizTalk as he/she typically sends to REST server. The aim is to practice BizTalk WCF-WebHttp adapters (for both receive and send). My idea is to handle all the API requests and methods in a single receive location, send port, orchestration. How can I achieve it? The reason I'm using orchestration is to map and do other process on the messages later.

- Does this idea wrong? Should we individually create send ports/receive locations for every API method?
- Is there any relation between the operation name of logical port in orchestration and operation name in WCF-WebHttp adapter URL mapping (`<Operation Name="SomeName" ... />`)? (to one single orchestration and handle all methods)
- How to design the desired orchestration? (I have tried 'Decide' shape (adding rules like `msg_input(BTS.Operation) == "SomeName"`) to separate different requests identified by URL mapping in the receive location and I was successful in this step, but is it the correct way either? However, I don't have any idea for designing shapes the way to correctly start orchestration. Also, I don't know ho to send requests from rule branches to send port within the orchestration)

I would also appreciate to hear any other suggestions for solving this problem in a different perspective.

Comment: Asking multiple questions in one question tends to get your questions closed.   Please edit your question so that it has only one question.  You can post more questions, and link them back to this one if it gives context

Comment: P.S. I've answered your question in the Microsoft Forum https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/03421b7b-028d-471a-a326-1e058567395d/consuming-rest-server-methods-using-biztalk-server-using-wcfwebhttp-adapter?forum=biztalkgeneral